# Linux: Is there something similar to "top" for I/O?

Tags: linux, process, top, io

My disk often is utilized, but `top` (and `htop`, a custom replacement) show nothing suspicious.

Is there a way to sort processes by I/O (more specific: disk) utilization?

**EDIT**
Found out using `iotop` that those strange processes are `flush-8:16` and `jbd2/sdb3-7`. Seems to have to do with usual filesystem operations.

Comment: If I'm correct flush and jbd concerns the sync of the journal (FS metadata) to the disk. Which means you must have some processes either writing to the disk or reading a lot of data and you have the atime option on your mount. I don't recommend this because some software relies on it (mutt and I have heard one backup tool) but you can set your mount to relatime or even "better" noatime. The latter will completely stop updating the access time (which incures a disk write) each time a file is read.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/how-can-i-monitor-disk-io

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/25032/linux-disk-io-load-breakdown-by-filesystem-path-and-or-process/25034#25034

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Have you tried `iotop` ?

You may need to install it before. Also, it depends on a kernel feature that may or may not enabled in your specific distribution.

Comment: Works on Mac OS X, too. Not sure that it is going to help with the problem at hand, though.

Comment: wow.  That's fantastic.  15+ years of admin work and I've never run into that.  Thanks!

Comment: Root access needed, FYI.

Answer (score 28):

You might want to give `atop` a try. It seems to do a good job of letting you know what is going on.

Comment: Seems to be better than `iotop` because it also shows IO busy percent.

Comment: Also no root or suid needed.

Answer (score 7):

`iostat` is still the king of detailed I/O information, the kind of info that can confirm if your SSD is living up to expectations, for example.

```
$ iostat -xht 5 nvme0n1
Linux 4.15.0-43-generic (myhost)    06/02/2021  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

06/02/2021 08:59:20 AM
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2.6%    0.1%    0.8%    0.1%    0.0%   96.4%

Device            r/s     w/s     rkB/s     wkB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
nvme0n1
                95.03   20.80      1.8M    300.1k     0.00    13.15   0.0%  38.7%    0.24    0.57   0.03    19.2k    14.4k   0.02   0.3%
```

Every five seconds, this will print detailed IO stats for the NVMe drive. The most important ones are usually not actually read/write bandwidth -- `rKB/s` and `wKB/s` -- but rather the reads and writes per second (`r/s` and `w/s`, aka IOPS) and, perhaps most important, the average time a process waited for each read and write -- `r_await` and `w_await` (in milliseconds).

All of these values feed into each other using the surprisingly useful Little's law formula, translated a bit to `latency = queue_size / IOPS`, or `await = aqu_sz / (r/s + w/s).`